# How to create a clone role in wordpress

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

How to create new role with same capabilities of existing role. 
Eg: I would like to create a new role with same capabilities of administrator or editor and so on..

Comment: What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? Have you tried [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)? Or [Capability Manager Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/capsman/)? Do they do the things you want?

Comment: You can use [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/) if you want to do everything visually :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this... This should work.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'cloneRole');

function cloneRole()
{
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    $adm = $wp_roles->get_role('administrator');
    //Adding a 'new_role' with all admin caps
    $wp_roles->add_role('new_role', 'My Custom Role', $adm->capabilities);
}
?>
```

Check it.

Comment: Watchout!! this seems to clone the role before the plugins add roles and capabilities. I'll try admin_init to see if this is better.

Comment: @spankmaster79 Yes please, that will be great!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde didn't work any better. Role is still ignored by the plugin

Answer (score 4):

You could always use the [User Role Editor](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin;

1. Install the plugin
2. Go to Users > User Role Editor
3. Click "Add Role" to the right
4. Choose the role you wish to duplicate from the "Make copy of" dropdown in the dialogue box
5. Click "Add Role" in the dialogue box

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to clone the editor.

```
$edr = $wp_roles->get_role('Editor');
add_role('clonerole', 'clone roles', $edr->capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

the system that worked in my case is this:

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'cloneRole');

function cloneRole() {
 $adm = get_role('administrator');
 $adm_cap= array_keys( $adm->capabilities ); //get administator capabilities
 add_role('new_role', 'My Custom Role'); //create new role
 $new_role = get_role('new_role');
  foreach ( $adm_cap as $cap ) {
   $new_role->add_cap( $cap ); //clone administrator capabilities to new role
  }
}
?>
```