# Allow roles below admin to add subscribers only

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I want to give a group of user types (Editor + a custom role) the add_users /create_users capability. The only catch is that I wanted to limit that capability to adding 'subscriber' type users only, and nothing above that. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This first step to making this happen is add the capability to `create_users` to a given role.  You do this be calling `get_role`, then using the `add_cap` method.  This only needs to be done once.  Here's an example that does it on plugin activation.

```
<?php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse42003_activation' );
function wpse42003_activation()
{
    foreach( array( 'editor', 'your_custome_role' ) as $r )
    {
        $role = get_role( $r );
        if( $role )
            $role->add_cap( 'create_users' );
    }
}
```

If you do that, you probably want to make sure to undo it on plugin deactivation with `remove_cap`.

```
<?php
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse42003_deactivation' );
function wpse42003_deactivation()
{
    foreach( array( 'editor', 'your_custome_role' ) as $r )
    {
        $role = get_role( $r );
        if( $role )
            $role->remove_cap( 'create_users' );
    }
}
```

Now the problem of making sure those users can only register subscribers.  On the `user-new.php` page, the roles drop down get generated by a function called `wp_dropdown_roles`, which in turn calls the function `get_editable_roles` to fetch the roles the current user can edit/create.

Fortunately for you, there's a filter in there that will allow us to modify this bit.  First we'll copy all the `$roles` array keys, then loop through and unset any role other than subscriber from `$roles` -- only if the current user has the role editor or your custom role.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'wpse42003_filter_roles' );
function wpse42003_filter_roles( $roles )
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( in_array( 'editor', $user->roles ) || in_array( 'your_custom_role', $user->roles ) )
    {
        $tmp = array_keys( $roles );
        foreach( $tmp as $r )
        {
            if( 'subscriber' == $r ) continue;
            unset( $roles[$r] );
        }
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

The bonus part of this is that `get_editable_roles` is called before a user is added or updated -- your editors won't be able to add users by insert extra options in the form with JS or something similar.

**note: change `your_custom_role` in the examples above to your role's name.**

All that [as a plugin](https://gist.github.com/1804462).

Comment: I kept looking for a way to filter the user insertion event, hoping to reject the attempt to add users above the desired level, but hadn't thought of simply filtering the dropdown. Thanks so much!

Comment: With making a few small adjustments to the code to suit my own needs, it still holds up in WP3.9.1 :)

Comment: FYI, I found that you have to have the following capabilities for this solution to work: `create_users`, `edit_users` and `list_users`. See a full explanation in my other comments. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @chrisguitarguy is good. I've made a small modification to the code to have it work from a development bureau serving customers on a multi-site install. We were in need to create a 'customer' user role, but of course a customer should not be allowed to add another customer to its domain. Modified from the accepted answer I've come to this:

```
/**
 * Add filter to ensure a Customer type can NOT create another Customer user
 */
add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'limit_create_user' );
function limit_create_user( $roles ){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( in_array( 'customer', $user->roles )){
        unset( $roles[ 'customer' ]);
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

Hoping someone might find some use for this in the future. This was tested and applied in WP3.9.1.

Comment: I've got similar situation. I've added the following capabilities `create_users` and `list_users`. I've also added `editable_roles` filter, which displays a specific role correctly. However, when I create a new user it's always a 'subscriber' and not a custom role. Has anyone came across this issue?

Comment: I personally haven't and would like the answer to that ;) Even when going into the database and manually changing `default_role` from `subscriber` to `anything`, after the next refresh of the site, or a specific blog in multi-site, the value has been reset to `subscriber`.

Comment: Ok, I've dug into the WP code for creating a user and figured out why it doesn't work. A user have to have `edit_users` capability to create a user with a role that's been selected from the drop-down menu. Otherwise, without `edit_users` capability a selected role from the drop-down is ignored and a default role is assigned to the new user (which is usually 'Subscriber' role, unless it was changed to something else). This is for standard non-multisite setup, multisite might need more capabilities for it to work.

Comment: So, to recap, for this solution to work, a user have to have the following capabilities `create_users`, `edit_users` and `list_users`, to be able to create only users of other specific roles - where a role is selected from a drop-down menu on 'Add New User' admin screen. I hope that helps! :)