# Hide Updates from Admins that don't equal a set Username

Tags: admin

Is there a way in WordPress that I can hide say Update Notices from other administrators unless there username is **equal** to say **main-admin**?

Essentially I want something like this:

```
if ( username != 'main-admin' ) {
    // Hide all updates
}
```

Is there a way to do this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try following:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if( user_can( $current_user, 'main-admin' ) ) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

> For more info please read in the Codex about:
>    [`user_can`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can) , [`wp_get_current_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

**Edit**: my mistake, was reading wrong, I thought you meant a custom role *main-admin*.
 *Not to make my mistake suddenly as correct, but maybe you create a role where the user belongs to. (is maybe even easier to manage?)*

---

**Add-on** *Trying to give an correct answer/option now.*

There are several ways/options to achieve your goal below are 2:

Knowing the name makes it able to use:  `get_currentuserinfo()`

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( $current_user->user_lastname ) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

> Codex: [`get_currentuserinfo`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo#Examples)

When you know the user id you could use `get_current_user_id()`:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ( $user_id == 5 ) {  // add correct id
    // Do your stuff 
}
```

> Codex: [`get_current_user_id`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_user_id)

---

As mentioned you can also create a custom role with administrator caps, which is explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/31472/15605) by @RutwickGangurde. To keep the answer here complete I added the code here.
**NB: The setting is saved to the database (in table wp_options, field wp_user_roles), so it needs to run only once**

I personally use a Class in `functions.php` to be sure a certain function only runs once, which in this case is a must!
Add both functions into your `functions.php` *(make first a copy!)*

```
class run_once
{
    function run( $key )
    {
        $scenario = get_option( 'run_once' );
        if ( isset( $scenario[$key] ) && $scenario[$key] )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $scenario[$key] = true;
            update_option( 'run_once', $scenario );
            return true;
        }
    } // end function
} // end class

// Now use the class with this function (which will only run once!)
$run_once = new run_once;
if ( $run_once->run( 'cloneRole' ) )
{       
    function cloneRole()
    {
        global $wp_roles;

        if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

        $adm = $wp_roles->get_role( 'administrator' );
        //Adding a 'new_role' with all admin caps
        $wp_roles->add_role( 'main-admin', 'Main Admin', $adm->capabilities );
    } // end Function
    add_action( 'init', 'cloneRole' );    
} // end if(..)
```

> Core info about [`add_role`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)

You can now add users to this custom role and use that role in other situations as in:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if( user_can( $current_user, 'main-admin' ) )
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try :)

Comment: Might be more robust to use a custom capability and then give that capability to this particular admin account.